# Accessing child node value with parent reference with LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am stuck with accessing child node value. Below is the XML structure and the code to create new contact.

```
<Order xmlns="http://example.com">
    <MiscContact>
        <MiscContact>
            <ContactType>MailingContact</ContactType>
            <Contact>
                <Name>
                    <First>JIM</First>                      
                    <Last>RON</Last>
                    <FullName>RON JIM</FullName>
                </Name>
                <IsValid>false</IsValid>
              </Contact>
        </MiscContact>
    </MiscContact> 
    <ExportForm>
        <Contact>
            <Name>
                <First>JIM</First>                      
                <Last>RON</Last>
                <FullName>RON JIM</FullName>                   
            </Name>                
        <IsValid>false</IsValid>
        </Contact>
    </ExportForm>
</Order>
```

Code to create new contact only for `<MiscContact>`:

```
XNamespace Namespace = "http://online.us.com";
var MiscContact = from mc in xmlDoc.Descendants(Namespace + "Contact") 
                  where mc.Parent.Name.Equals("MiscContact")
                  select new Contact
                  { Name = ob.Element(Namespace + "Name").Value }
```

Issue i encountered is that even though i have where clause to select only contact whose parent is MiscContact, but contact section both from `<MiscContact>` and `<ExportForm>` are getting loaded.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be working correctly with the `where` clause and pulls the `Name` element from `MiscContact -> Contact -> Name`. I think your problem is that you're using `.Value` in the end, which concatenates all these values together:

```
<Name>
  <First>JIM</First>                      
  <Last>RON</Last>
  <FullName>RON JIM</FullName>
</Name>
```

The result is "JIMRONRON JIM". If you need the `"FullName"` then you should use:

```
mc.Element(Namespace + "Name")
  .Element(Namespace + "FullName").Value
```

Replace `"FullName"` with `"First"` or `"Last"` as needed.